# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{{\rm d}x}{(x+2)(2x+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

could someone explain me through the following problem, please?

> $$
> \int_0^\infty\frac{{\rm d}x}{(x+2)(2x+1)}
> $$

I am looking for steps for understanding, not the direct answer :)

Comment: Have you tried partial fraction?

Comment: Suggest to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand $\frac{1}{(x+2)(2x+1)}$ is a rational function of the form $f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials in $x$ with $Q(x)\not\equiv 0$. Partial fraction decomposition can be used to integrate rational functions. In this technique we decompose a single rational function into a sum of simpler rational functions. In your case, we need to find $A$ and $B$ which satisfy

$$\frac{1}{(x+2)(2x+1)} = \frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{2x+1}$$

multiplying the LHS and RHS by $(x+2)(2x+1)$ forms

$$1=A(2x+1)+B(x+2)$$

which allows us to solve for $A$ and $B$

$$x=-\frac{1}{2} \implies 1 =\frac{3}{2}B \implies B=\frac{2}{3}$$
$$x=-2 \implies 1 =-3A \implies A=-\frac{1}{3}$$

therefore the original integral becomes

$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{{\rm d}x}{(x+2)(2x+1)}=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1/3}{x+2}+\frac{2/3}{2x+1}\right)\,dx
$$

which can be solved through known techniques of the logarithm function.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding $A$ and $B$ such that:
$$\frac{1}{(x+2)(2x+1)} = \frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{2x+1}.$$

Comment: Is there any easy way of finding A and B ?

Comment: Simplifying the expression on the right hand side, we get:
$$\frac{A(2x+1)+B(x+2)}{(x+2)(2x+1)}.$$
What value of A and B makes the numerator 1. Hint: We don't want $x$'s in our numerator.

Comment: See the answer above. Essentially, multiply both sides by $(x+2)(2x+1)$, then remember that this needs to be an identity (true for all values of $x$).